# How to test a Camel in Spring Boot Camel project - all @EndpointInject are null but @Autowired working?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, apache-camel

I have a yet very simple Spring Boot (2.5.1)/ Apache Camel (3.10.0) Application and i am struggling creating a simple test. In my case it even fails to inject endpoints:

So my first simple try is to get this green:

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
class UnmarshalXmlTest {

    @EndpointInject("mock:out")
    MockEndpoint outEndpoint;
    
    @Produce("direct:in")
    ProducerTemplate template;
    
    @Test
    void test() {
        assertNotNull(outEndpoint);
        assertNotNull(template);
    }

}
```

But it is red. Sadly [the documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/testing.html#Testing-SpringTestwithJavaConfigExample) is outdated (uses deprecated SingleRouteCamelConfiguration) and it is also not showing how to test a given route. The [other doc](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/test-spring-junit5.html#_using_the_camelspringtest_annotation) is also not helping (using `@CamelSpringTest` instead is not helping).

It seems that spring annotations are working - adding stuff via `@Autowired` works!

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61027107/447426) suggests that it should just work?! So how to get the camel annotations picked up and working?

Comment: In my case adding `@SpringBootTest` annotation along with `@CamelSpringBootTest` did the trick for camel 3.4

Comment: this did it indeed - too bad that documentation is missing this detail. On the other hand Spring boot related stuff like @Autowired is working. so this fix is not really obvious. make it an answer and earn some points :-)

Comment: hi! glad I could help, made it an answer as you suggested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you also need @SpringBootTest annotation to get it solved

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest
class UnmarshalXmlTest {
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is really odd "@CamelSpringBootTest" provides spring context but without camel context (camel annotations are null because there is no camecontext). as soon as a camelcontext is present the camel annotations begin to work.